# Why do we use Integration tools such as jitterbit or informatica when we have Rest API to call different applications?

Tags: java, rest, integration, informatica, jitterbit

Why do we use Integration tools such as jitterbit or informatica when we have Rest API to call different applications such as Java based app, SFDC app, any cloud based third party API etc.

Comment: any idea about what ETL is about? and what is Integration? Maybe it is a time to read something about?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you are using it as a Man in the Middle type of software.  For instance, Salesforce has one form of data and NetSuite has another.  The fields are not the same, the data types are not the same, the validations are not the same, etc...  A basic function of JitterBit is that it allows you to connect two systems and transform the data in-between them, so that they can easily talk to each other.  You can get much more advanced than that, though.  But, essentially you will need something to convert the data between the two systems, and JitterBit does that.

Comment: And there's more! Not all applications have APIs, not everything needs to be re-invented (need data from SAP?), you get performance & efficiency, auditing, monitoring. You also get data lineage that helps a lot in impact or root cause analysis. And there's still more! :)